# Need help finding the mistake in the C programme

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to calculate value of sin(x) in C but I am getting black screen in code:block after execution, its taking long for compilation and execution.

```
#include<stdio.h>

float mult(float x, int m, int i) {
  float a = x;
  if (i == m) {
    return x;
  } else {
    i++;
    a = a * mult(x, m, i);
    return a;
  }
}

int fact(int m) {
  printf("%d! ", m); fflush(stdout);

  int b;
  if (m == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    b = m * fact(m - 1);
    return b;
  }
}

float term(float x, int m) {
  float a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
  int i = 0;
  a = mult(x, m, i);
  b = fact(m);
  c = a / (1.0 * b);
  return c;
}

float sinof(float x, int m, int n) {
  float b = 0;
  if (m >= 10) {
    return (0);
  } else {
    printf("......%d  ", m); fflush(stdout);
    b = term(x, m);
    m = m + 2;
    n = -n;
    b = b + (n * sinof(x, m, n));
    return b;
  }
}

int main() {
  float x = 0, sin = 0;
  int m = 1, n = 1;
  printf("Enter the angle in radians:");
  scanf("%f", &x);
  sin = sinof(x, m, n);
  printf("%f", sin);
}
```

I hope the logic is correct.

Comment: Fixing the indentation would be a good start.  It's pretty hard for anyone to read as it is.

Comment: At a first glance it seems that sinof() will never stop calling itself. Since m starts with 1 and is incremented by 2 before each subsequent recursive call, it will never get the value of 10 which would allow it to end.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn [how to debug a small program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @NateEldredge True format was difficult.  On the plus side, code did compile fairly well will only 3 warnings (-pedantic -Wall -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion).

Comment: Thanks  Nate Eldredge, Manos Anastasiadis,lurker and chux - Reinstate Monica for your help and sorry for bad editing of code in the question (that is because i am new to stack)+chux - Reinstate Monica thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1):

`m` is odd.  Below fails to stop recursion.

```
if(m==10){  // Never true 
    return(0);
} else{
  b=term(x,m);
  m=m+2;n=-n;  // ***********
  b=b+(n*sinof(x,m,n));
  return b;
}
```

I recommend OP get own code working first.  There are various other issues.
For a simplified recursive `sine()`, mouse over to see.

> static double my_sin_helper(double xx, double term, unsigned n) {
>    if (term + 1.0 == 1.0) {
>      return term;
>    }
>    return term -  my_sin_helper(xx, xx *term / ((n + 1) * (n + 2)), n + 2);
>  }
>
>  // valid for [-pi/2 + pi/2]
>  double my_sin_primary(double x) {
>    return x * my_sin_helper(x * x, 1.0, 1);
>  }

Comment: Sorry i couldn't get this code can you explain a bit for me, thank you

Comment: @shubham108 Let's narrow things.  What part was unclear?

Comment: I used the formula sin(x)=x-(x^3/3!)+(x^5/5!)-(x^7/7!)+... which formula are you using in the above code ...

Comment: @shubham108 Same formula.